# PHP PDO:Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: php, pdo

I've been searching for a while but I can't solve my problem.

Here's the code

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM %s WHERE";
$cDatas = count($datas);
$inputs = [':string'=>$string];
for ($i=0; $i < $cDatas; $i++) {
     $inputs[':col' . $i] = $datas[$i];
     if ($i > 0) {
         $sql.=" OR LOWER(:col". $i .") REGEXP ':string'";
     }else{
         $sql.=" LOWER(:col0) REGEXP ':string'";
        }
     }
     $sql = sprintf($sql, $this->table);
     $pds = $this->cx->prepare($sql);
     $pds->execute($inputs); //the line concerned by the error
     return $pds->fetchAll();
```

the line concerned by the error message is the execute one.
I made var_dump to see what's wrong in the code.

```
var_dump($sql) : 
string 'SELECT * FROM %s WHERE LOWER(:col0) REGEXP ':string'' (length=52)

var_dump($inputs) : 
array (size=2) ':string' => string 'her' (length=3) ':col0' => string 'title' (length=5)
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: You cannot use `:col` and `:col0` as you are intending to. They won't be passed as column names, but as literal strings. Placeholders are strictly for scalar values, never for table or column identifiers.

Comment: ...assuming that's what you are trying to do.  Please post an example of what `:col . $i` will contain, and the structure of your table.

Answer (score -1):

It is probably better not to mix named and non-named parameters as in `SELECT * FROM %s WHERE LOWER(:col0) REGEXP ':string'`.

The code you want probably reads like `SELECT * FROM my_table_name WHERE LOWER(:col) REGEXP :string`.

I.e. do not put quotes around string arguments in prepared statements.

Also the named parameter `:col0` does not match the named value `:col`.